# How to set gravity of text toast (new solution for gravity in center ) for android api 11?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-toast, android-11

Setgravity method has removed for api 11 .have any another way to use gravity center of text toast.

Comment: if it's removed, probably means you shouldn't be doing it. are you sure there isn't a recommended replacement ?

Comment: Indeed, you shouldn't mess with the Toast's gravity. They are intended for very specific use-cases (less and less, since Google prefers you use Snackbars where possible); since they are system-wide (and difficult to know which app triggered them), Google wants to make sure they are consistent. And to that effect, they also added now the app icon to it so users can identify who triggered the Toast.